# How can I get the postback argument from initializeRequest event in ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, events

I capture the initializeRequest AJAX event using `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(InitializePostback)`.

Inside the `InitializePostback` function, I can successfully get the item that triggered the postback by calling `args.get_postBackElement()`, but this is not enough info for me, I also need to get the postback argument that was sent with the postback. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out what I need to do. Because the postback event argument is allways stored in a hidden tag named "__EVENTARGUMENT", we can simply access that:

```
var postbackArgument = document.getElementById('__EVENTARGUMENT');
if (postbackArgument) if (postbackArguments.value == 'Objects') {
 // Do stuff here
}
```

I was not sure if this value was set at the time the `initializeRequest` AJAX event was triggered, but when I tried it worked. Yess!